# Proof of infinite solutions for equidistant point

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products

Given two points $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^k, k\geq 3$ and one scalar $r \in \mathbb{R}$, the goal is to prove that there are an infinite amount of points $z \in \mathbb{R}^k$ such that:
$$|z - x| = |z - y| = r$$

Graphically, all vectors $z$ should form a hyperplane sitting in between $x$ and $y$.

I couldn't find a way to algebraically manipulate the equation, and I'm pretty sure that operating on the components is out of the question.

My next approach was constructing a vector which satisfied the equation, and then show that scaling it would not affect the result. Intuitively, this would be a vector $b$ such that:

$$b \cdot (x - y) = 0$$

eminating from the midpoint between $x$ and $y$:

$$z = \frac{1}{2}(x + y) + \alpha b, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$$

I think this defines an infinite subset of all $z$ values, but I've had no luck trying to plug it back into the equation.

Comment: Please be more specific about $r$. Also, you need $k\ge 3$.

Comment: Why do you need $k \geq 3$?

Comment: And now you need $r>2|x-y|$. Also, you seem to be on the wrong track: only a certain subset of that hyperplane satisfies your equation.

Comment: You need $k\ge 3$ because in $\mathbb R^2$, at most two points $z$ can satisfy your equation.

Comment: Ah I see. Well, the idea was that if I can show a subset of the solution set is infinite, then the solution set itself must be infinite

Comment: But scaling $b$ _does_ affect the result! You must try something else. Try to visualise it in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Are you sure? In $\mathbb{R}^3$ all points equidistant from $x$ and $y$ lie in a plane including the midpoint which is perpendicular to $x$ and $y$, or in other words, whose normal is parallel to $(x - y)$

Comment: Yes, but not all points in that plane have distance $r$ to $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Oh wow totally missed that thanks, must have gotten carried away by the picture I drew to visualize this